# Como implementar Design Pattern para um proxy de microservices?

Tags: php, proxy, microsserviços, middleware

Em breve iremos fazer nossas aplicações através de **Middlewares**, sei que a autenticação dos sistemas vai ser através de [**OAuth2**](http://oauth.net/2/), porém estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Por onde devo começar a estudar assuntos relacionados e como poderia adaptar as aplicações que já temos para um design pattern que trabalhe nesse nível de arquitetura. Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo simples, de como implementaria um sistema de e-mail por exemplo?

Comment: Acho que você está usando o termo "Design Pattern" de maneira inadequada. Eles apenas vão indicar uma forma de resolver um problema determinado, não a arquitetura da aplicação como um todo. O que você quer não se resolve aplicando um único design pattern por exemplo, você precisa definir as fronteiras da sua aplicação e como os pontos vão se conectar. Como não tenho prática com as tecnologias mencionadas, não posso te ajudar.

Comment: Pelo que sei, o microservice é um pattern ou não? O que preciso saber é como fazê-lo...

Comment: Sim. É um padrão, mas talvez não de desenho. Quando você diz "Design Pattern" isso remete mais à uma solução de um "pequeno" problema e não um padrão arquitetural. Microservices vêm ganhando popularidade ultimamente, mas te aconselho a pesquisar bastante à respeito do conceito, antes de ir para uma implementação.Digo isso porque desconheço algum "Hello World with microservices", embora não duvide que exista.  Vou lhe indicar um podcast que acredito que possa acrescentar na sua busca: http://tecnologicamentearretado.com.br/2015/08/03/microsservicos-com-renan-martins/